# Authentication from scratch: "undefined method `find_by_username`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, basic-authentication, filemaker

I'm trying to include a simple user authentication into my application, based on a filemaker database (using the ginjo-rfm gem). After getting some ideas from Ryan Bates' [Authentication from Scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch), I've written a customized version of it, but running into some problems.

When I submit my login form, I'm presented with

> undefined method `find_by_username' for User:Class

The find_by_username method should be based on a column in the database called 'username', is it not?

**User.rb**

```
class User < Rfm::Base
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :username, :password

   config :layout => 'web__SupplierContacts'

  def self.authenticate(username, password)
    user = find_by_username(username)
    if user && user.password_hash == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, user.password_salt)
      user
    else
      nil
    end
  end  

end
```

**sessions_controller.rb**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
 def new
 end

 def create
   user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])
      if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
     session[:user_id] = user.id
     redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged in!"
   else
     flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid"
     render "new"
   end
 end

 def destroy
   session[:user_id] = nil
   redirect_to root_url, notice: "Logged out!"
 end
end
```

I'm guessing this is a problem with my model inheriting from Rfm::Base, but I'm not sure. **Any ideas?**

**Idea:**
Is there any way to rephrase the `Class.find_by_column` statement? I'm not able to do `User.where(:username => "username usernamerson"`, either (returns `undefined method 'where' for User:Class`).

Comment: Yes, my database has a "Username" column, which is translated and mapped in my User model. In the console, I can do User.find(:username => "some.dude") and it returns correctly. I'm not migrating since I'm working in a filemaker database, which breaks some of the standard ruby workflow.

Comment: Where is `Rfm::Base` defined?

Comment: I'm assuming `Rfm::Base` extends `ActiveRecord::Base`?

Comment: Rfm::Base is a part of the ginjo-rfm gem. Rfm::Base do not extend ActiveRecord - that's kinda the heart of this question - How can I 1) define the find_by/where methods or 2) Rephrase the line 'user = find_by_username(username)' without using 'find_by' and 'where'. It may be worth mentioning that Rfm::Base is extended by ActiveModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Rfm::Base` does not extend `ActiveRecord`, then you won't be able to use the activerecord db query methods like `find`, `where`, etc. -- they are part of the `ActiveRecord` class and only available to classes which inherit from it.

If you want to include database wrapper methods in a class which extends another class (in this case `Rfm::Base`), you might have a look at [DataMapper](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html), which takes the form of a module (and thus can be included in any class). (DataMapper can be used as a replacement for ActiveRecord in Rails apps.)

Also, you've included `ActiveModel::SecurePassword` twice:

```
class User < Rfm::Base
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  include ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
```

I'd delete one of those.